# How many of my dice will show "1"?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

So I have a set of fair dice, except not all of them are 1-6.  Here are the seven fair dice:

- 1d4: 1 - 4
- 1d6: 1 - 6
- 1d8: 1 - 8
- 2d10: 1 - 10 each
- 1d12: 1 - 12
- 1d20: 1 - 20

If I roll all of these dice, on average how many of my dice will show a 1?  How many will show a 5?  (I imagine 2 & 3 will have the same average number as 1).

If these all had the same number of faces I'm pretty confident I could work the answer out using a binomial distribution, but with them all different values I'm not sure exactly how to go about it.  Can you use multiple binomial distributions somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can calculate the expected number of 1's using the [linearity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value).  Let $X_1$ denote the random variable that is $1$ if the 4-sided die rolls a 1, and $0$ otherwise.  Similarly, let $X_2$ denote the indicator variable for the 6-sided die, and $X_3,\ldots, X_7$ for the other dice.  We have $X_1+X_2+\cdots +X_7$ indicating the total number of 1's showing, and $$E(X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_7)=E(X_1)+E(X_2)+\cdots +E(X_7)$$
by the aforementioned theorem.

Now, the separate expectations are easy to calculate, $E(X_1)=1/4$, $E(X_2)=1/6$, and so on.  Hence the desired answer for 1's is $$\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{2}{10}+\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{20}=\frac{7}{8}$$

For the second question, the expected number of 5's, the method is the same, except now $E(X_1)=0$, since we can't get a 5 on a 4-sided die.  Hence the answer is $$\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{2}{10}+\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{20}=\frac{5}{8}$$

Comment: Perfect! Concise and well explained, thank you very much

Comment: Actually I have a question now that I'm home and can look more closely. Wouldn't this suggest that about 7/8 of the dice will be ones, but also 7/8 of them will be twos? That's more than all of the dice... Either I'm interpreting this wrong or you answered a slightly different question?

Comment: @realityChemist I believe the interpretation is that on average when you roll these dice, less than one die is expected to come up 1. In particular, on average you should expect to see 7 cumulative ones for every 8 times you throw the dice.

Comment: Ahh, okay, I can work with that, thank you